# Proximity for OpenLayers

Tags: 7, javascript

It has a bug that keeps dumping errors to the logs.  There is a patch, but the patch removes the distance field.  The module isn't maintained.

Does anyone know of other modules that can be used with OpenLayers and views to plot locations within a particular radius?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) module 2.x. It contains proximity capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to instructions on Drupal.org for creating proximity search using Open Layers.

It's fallen a little behind updates to the process, but I'm going to try and update it very soon.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1714680